# Copying file from one directory to another

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Does anyone know how I can copy/duplicate a file from one directory into another without specification of src path? I got it to work with "shutil.copy2" but it's not exactly what I am looking for since the src argument asks for the path.

My goal is to be able to copy/duplicate a file from one directory into another by filename. Has anyone done this before, if so can you guide me in the right direction? - Thanks

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# These params will be used for specifying which template you want to copy and where to output 
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
'''Load file from x directory into current working directory '''

#PullTemplate: Specify which template you want to copy, by directory path
TemplateRepo = ("/home/hadoop/BackupFolders/Case_Project/scripts")

#OutputTemplate: Let's you specify where you want to output the copied template.
#Originally set to your current working directory (u".")
OutputTemplate = (u".")


shutil.copy2(TemplateRepo, OutputTemplate)
```

Comment: by filename?? that would mean scan your entire filesystem for matching filename(s)... makes no sense unless you narrow that down.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. The code I have now worked and gets the job done, but the team asked if I can find a way to just call the file by name rather than by path because it's still extra work to go get the path of the file and if we do that we might as well just duplicated the file in Jupyter nb. The end goal is for the user to just be prompted "Which file would you like to pull". The user will then type in the file name and it will be copied into their current directory. @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: what if there are many files with the same name? should it copy all of them (makes no sense?)

Comment: Thank you. I brought this up to my manager right now. He said I can just have all the template files in one directory and then pull them by name. So  I'm thinking that now I will just specify the path name for the directory and then find a way to specify which file to copy from the dir. Thanks again, for your help. I am an intern with very minimal formal education, everything I know is learned on the go.

Comment: This assignment sounds a bit non-sensical, but it might be because we don't know the context; why would anyone _not_ want to specify the path to the file? What is the broader context, i.e. the application or task that this is a part of?  If we knew that the question might make more sense, and might have a sensible answer.

Comment: @alexis Clarification: We are specifying the path in the backend. The goal is for end users to be prompted with "Which file would you like to pull". So far I created a new folder containing all the file templates. I specified the directory path, now I'm trying to use a raw_Input so user can specify which file they want. More clear? My apology for not providing correct logic. New to programming, i know that is an area where i lack in.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are trying to load a file in the same project you need to have at least the folder name inside that project.

You can use json

Something like this.

```
import json

#someFiles is just a fold name inside the projects main folder.
with open("someFiles\\file_name", "r") as whatever_u_want:
    var_of_choice = json.load(whatever_u_want)


print (var_of_choice)
```

once the file is open you can save the variable `var_of_choice` as any file name you wish where you wish using the json dump method.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the file you want to copy, create a duplicate of the file by choosing Duplicate key under File ( below the Jupyter logo at the top ).
2. Choose the file copied(file_copy), and choose Move key under File.
3. Choose the file path where you want to paste/move the copied file.
4. Rename the copied file name as you wish.

For more info, you can refer to here: https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781785884870/1/ch01lvl1sec12/basic-notebook-operations